# Have subfiles declare sections to be included in different places of the document

Tags: input

I'd like to have several Latex files, imported or included in a master `document.tex` file, which declare different sections to be included in the master file, like:

```
% in file a.tex
\begin{notes}
My notes from file A
\end{notes}

\begin{examples}
An example from file A
\end{examples}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% in file b.tex
\begin{notes}
My notes from file B
\end{notes}

\begin{examples}
An example from file B
\end{examples}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% in file document.tex

\section{Notes}
% input notes from a.tex and b.tex

\section{Examples}
% input examples from a.tex and b.tex
```

And have the following output:

```
Notes
My notes from file A
My notes from file B

Examples
An example from file A
An example from file B
```

I could have 4 separate files instead of 2 (`a.notes.tex`, `a.examples.tex`, etc), but I'd like to keep everything related to `a` in a single file, if possible. Do you know if there is a way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, You can use the [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package. In the file `document.tex` you declare the two collections (`notes` and `examples`) using `\definecollection`, and define the two associated environments (`note` and `example`) using `collect`:

```
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{notes}
\definecollection{examples}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{note}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{notes}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{examples}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother
```

In each of the files `a.tex` and `b.tex` you can then use these environments to write your notes and example:

#### File `a.tex`:

```
\begin{note}
First note in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{note}
Second note in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{note}
Third note in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{example}
First example in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Second example in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{example}
```

#### File `b.tex`:

```
\begin{note}
First note in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{note}
Second note in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{example}
First example in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Second example in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Third example in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\end{example}
```

Then, in `document.tex` you include files `a` and `b` and use `\includecoleection` at the point where the collections must be included. A complete example `document.tex` would look like:

#### File `document.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{notes}
\definecollection{examples}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{note}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{notes}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{examples}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother

\input{a}\input{b}

\begin{document}

\section{Notes}
\includecollection{notes}

\section{Examples}
\includecollection{examples}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, Gonzalo!

Comment: @spalladino You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: Actually, the collect is throwing some errors when the collected content has listings or comment environments in it. Do you know if this is a known issue, or if there is workaround? Thanks!

Comment: @spalladino Hmmm... yes, verbatim material can be a problem. I think the best thing to do here would be to open a follow-up question, providing there a little example (similar to the one in my answer) with your current settings.