# Using collect to gather content with listings, comments or verbatims

Tags: listings, verbatim, comments

I was looking into a way to set up a project with multiple files, in which several files could declare content to be included in different sections of the main tex document. After [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127758/have-subfiles-declare-sections-to-be-included-in-different-places-of-the-documen/127776), I decided to go with the `collect` package.

However, if the text I'm including has any `verbatim`, `lstlisting` or `comment` content, the compilation fails.

As an example, based on the answer provided by Gonzalo Medina in the previous question:

First, to declare environments which will collect the content in the subfiles:

```
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{notes}
\definecollection{examples}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{note}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{notes}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{examples}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother
```

In files `a.tex` and `b.tex`, which will provide the content for the main file:

#### File `a.tex`:

```
\begin{note}
First note in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{note}
Second note in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\begin{comment}
Hidden note in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{comment}
\end{note}

\begin{example}
\begin{lstlisting}
Code example with listings in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{example}

\begin{example}
\begin{verbatim}
Code example in verbatim in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{verbatim}
\end{example}
```

#### File `b.tex`:

```
\begin{note}
First note in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{note}
Second note in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\begin{comment}
Hidden note in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\end{comment}
\end{note}

\begin{example}
\begin{lstlisting}
Code example with listings in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{example}

\begin{example}
\begin{verbatim}
Code example in verbatim in file \texttt{b.tex}.
\end{verbatim}
\end{example}
```

Main document then includes both files and renders first the `notes` collection followed by the `examples` collection:

#### File `document.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{comment}

\definecollection{notes}
\definecollection{examples}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{note}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{notes}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{examples}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother

\input{a}\input{b}

\begin{document}

\section{Notes}
\includecollection{notes}

\section{Examples}
\includecollection{examples}

\end{document}
```

So the result should be:

```
Notes

First note in file a.tex
Second note in file a.tex
First note in file b.tex
Second note in file b.tex

Examples

Code example with listings in file a.tex
Code example with verbatim in file a.tex
Code example with listings in file b.tex
Code example with verbatim in file b.tex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, but it requires some additional work: the idea is to box the special content. For the case of `verbatim` or `lstlisting`, it's enough to box the content (using an `lrbox`, for example); in the case of comments, you can define a `\specialcomment` that boxes its contents first. An example:

#### File document.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{notes}
\definecollection{examples}

\includecomment{test}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{note}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{notes}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\@nameuse{collect}{examples}{\par\noindent}{\par}{}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\input{a}

\section{Notes}
\includecollection{notes}

\section{Examples}
\includecollection{examples}

\end{document}
```

#### File a.tex (with listings and comments):

```
\newsavebox\myboxa
\begin{lrbox}{\myboxa}
\begin{lstlisting}
test listing
%&/(%$#_^
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\newsavebox\myboxb
\specialcomment{test}{\begin{lrbox}{\myboxb}}{\end{lrbox}}
\begin{test}
Some comment in the file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{test}

\begin{note}
First note in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{note}
Second note in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{note}
Third note in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{note}

\begin{example}
First example in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Second example in file \texttt{a.tex}.
\end{example}

\begin{note}
\usebox\myboxb
\end{note}

\begin{example}
\usebox\myboxa
\end{example}
```

The resulting document:

[image]